# How to loop through sub-folders?

Tags: vba, excel

I have VBA code that returns external file details like path, type, last modified date, last created date etc. for files in a folder.

I want to return the details for files in the sub-folders of that folder.

```vb
Dim IRow

Sub ListFiles()
    IRow = 11 'where you want your first row of data
    Call ListMyFiles(Range("B5"), False) 'Where B5 is your filepath (eg, C:\)
End Sub
    
Sub ListMyFiles(MySourcePath, includesubfolders)
    Dim xSubFolder As Object
    Set MyObject = New FileSystemObject
    Set mysource = MyObject.GetFolder(MySourcePath)
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each myfile In mysource.Files
        icol = 1
        Cells(IRow, icol).Value = myfile.Path
        icol = icol + 1
        Cells(IRow, icol).Value = myfile.Name
        icol = icol + 1
        Cells(IRow, icol).Value = myfile.Type
        icol = icol + 1
        Cells(IRow, icol).Value = myfile.DateLastModified
        icol = icol + 1
        Cells(IRow, icol).Value = myfile.DateCreated
        icol = icol + 1
           
        IRow = IRow + 1
    Next
    If xIsSubfolders Then
        For Each xSubFolder In xFolder.subfolders
            ListFilesInFolder xSubFolder.Path, True
        Next xSubFolder
    End If
    Set xFile = Nothing
    Set xFolder = Nothing
    Set xFileSystemObject = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried this far

Comment: Please see my updated code above to see what I did so far.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but basically what you want is recursion. This is when you call the subroutine/function while in that function. Basically it's the subroutine calling itself every time it finds a subfolder.

Something like:

```
Dim IRow
Sub ListFiles() 
    IRow = 11 'where you want your first row of data    
    Call ListMyFiles(Range("B5"), False) 'Where B5 is your filepath (eg, C:\)
End Sub

Sub ListMyFiles(MySourcePath as string, includesubfolders as boolean)


    Set MyObject = New FileSystemObject
    Set mysource = MyObject.GetFolder(MySourcePath)

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each myfile In mysource.Files
        icol = 1
        Cells(IRow, icol).Value = myfile.Path
        icol = icol + 1
        Cells(IRow, icol).Value = myfile.Name
        icol = icol + 1
        Cells(IRow, icol).Value = myfile.Type
        icol = icol + 1
        Cells(IRow, icol).Value = myfile.DateLastModified
        icol = icol + 1
        Cells(IRow, icol).Value = myfile.DateCreated
        icol = icol + 1

        IRow = IRow + 1
    Next

    'Check if the subroutine was called to include subfolders
    If includesSubFolders Then
        'Loop through all of the subfolders in the FSO folder
        For Each SubFolder in mysource.SubFolders
            'Call this same subroutine
            ListMyFiles(Subfolder.Path, true)
        Next xSubFolder
    End If      


End Sub
```

Comment: I see a syntax error at ListMyFiles(Subfolder.Path, true) statement. Can you please let me know on how to correct that ?

Comment: I am not sure. It looks fine to me. Perhaps put a breakpoint on that line and look at the SubFolder in the Locals pane. See if `Path` is an attribute and what it's value is. Make sure that the sub is defined with `Sub ListMyFiles(MySourcePath as string, includesubfolders as boolean)` there is a chance that it may expect that MySourcePath as a variant (undefined) type that is getting set as a "Range" since the initial call into the recursive subroutine is using a range object. Also you may change `Call ListMyFiles(Range("B5"), False)` to `Call ListMyFiles(Range("B5").Value, False)`

Comment: #sat #JNewill, you must "Call" to before "ListMyFiles(Subfolder.Path, true)"

Answer (score 0):

A lot of things can be simplified here. More importantly, the folder transversing needs to be a recursive call in order to go through to all subfolder levels.

Here is a sample code that does this. The first argument to `ListMyFiles` is the cell location where the path is stored, and the second argument when you want the file list to start.

```
Sub ListFiles()
    Call ListMyFiles(Sheet1.Range("B5"), Sheet1.Range("B11"), True)
End Sub

Sub ListMyFiles(ByVal r_SourcePath As Range, ByRef r_List As Range, Optional includesubfolders As Boolean = False)
    Dim path As String, ff As Folder
    path = r_SourcePath.Text
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Set ff = fso.GetFolder(path)
    Call ListFileInFolder(r_List, ff, includesubfolders)
End Sub

Public Sub ListFileInFolder(ByRef r_List As Range, ByRef ff As Folder, Optional inclSubFolders As Boolean = False)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim index As Long, n As Long
    index = 0
    Dim f As File
    For Each f In ff.Files
        r_List.Offset(index, 0).Resize(1, 5).Value2 = _
            Array(f.path, f.Name, f.Type, f.DateLastModified, f.DateCreated)
        index = index + 1
    Next
    If inclSubFolders Then
        For Each ff In ff.SubFolders
            n = ff.Files.Count
            If n > 0 Then
                Call ListFileInFolder(r_List.Offset(index, 0), ff, True)
                index = index + n
            End If
        Next
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Of note here is the writing of a single row of data of 5 columns using a single line and the `Array()` function.